# Error in manifest file for Firefox OS?

Tags: javascript, json, html, firefox-os

Why does this manifest file throw and error on the name in the developer section?

```
{
"name":"Hello World",
"description":"Our first application",
"launch_path":"/hello.html",
"version":"1.0",
"developer":"
         "name":"Simple Programmer",
         "url":"http://simpleprogrammer.com"
},
"icons":{
    "60":"/icon_60.png"
},
"default_locale":"en"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not a valid JSON, specifically this part:

```
"developer":"
         "name":"Simple Programmer",
         "url":"http://simpleprogrammer.com"
},
```

should be:

```
"developer": {
         "name":"Simple Programmer",
         "url":"http://simpleprogrammer.com"
},
```

Note the change in the first line - opening curly bracket (`{`) instead of a quotation mark (`"`).

Comment: Why does some Firefox OS phones say Android on them? Or does Firefox os have to have the Android running behind it.

Comment: Firefox OS consists of three layers: Gonk, Gecko and Gaia. The middle one, Gecko, is basically the same Gecko as on desktop Firefox. Gaia is the user interface, this is what the phone user sees on the screen. All applications run in Gaia. And now Gonk - the most bottom layer - it's based on Android. What Mozilla did is actually take the Android, remove all the upper layers (Java/Dalvik stuff) and replace it with Gecko and Gaia. And that's why you'd see Firefox OS running on Android devices - it's easiest for Mozilla developers to use them, as they has been on the market for a long time.

Comment: Do you think that it will come around and be more than it is? It is easy to develop applications with html5 and Javascript. But how is the Firefox OS coming in terms of popularity.

Comment: So basically just because it says Android doesn't just mean google and java it is just the foundation that everything else is built upon.

Comment: when you mean Gecko on a desktop Firefox OS is that the browser that interprets the html code.

Answer (score -1):

Also note that a 128x128 icon is required for Firefox Marketplace, see
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest#Required_icon_sizes

Comment: What are some of the other aspects of firefox os. I have a asteroids game I thought about putting up for free but how would i control it on the screen. Right now i use the arrows in the simulator and such. I don't have an actual device yet but have ordered one.